Python PYQT6 Working with a window, rounding the edges
I have a problem with the PyQT6 window - is that I hid the default window using
self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint) And as a result, I need to round the edges of the window, my problem is that they are crookedly rounded, I probably use a bad way, but it's the only working one, I really need help! Thank you all
The code for rounding the window is
class FramelessWidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.ico'))
        self.setWindowTitle("TEST")

        # Remove window borders and make it transparent
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)

        # Set window size
        self.resize(850, 590)
        self.setMinimumSize(850, 590)
        self.setMaximumSize(850, 590)

        self.setMask(self.create_rounded_region(20))

    def create_rounded_region(self, radius):
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), radius, radius)
        return QRegion(path.toFillPolygon().toPolygon())

I attached a screenshot of the uneven edges
I tried the help of the neural network and searched the Internet for 2-3 days, it did not help

I assume that another solution is needed to round the window

See also: Antialiasing (add smoothness) when masking a window for round-corner in PyQt5.
